# Halting at 95% emitting index-html-webpack-plugin (Angular ver. 7)

Tags: angular, webpack

Solution for Halting Problem at "ng build --prod 95% emitting index-html-webpack-plugin" (Angular version 7) when set "sourceMap": true in angular.json

Thanks!

Comment: Here go you: [Google Halting at 95% emitting index html webpack plugin Angular 7](https://www.google.com/search?q=Halting+at+95%25+emitting+index+html+webpack+plugin+Angular+7). If you want help on [so] please see [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 7):

To me this happened when playing with a different project in angular.json, and the referenced index.html file did not exist.

Comment: This was absolutely my issue as well the path to the index.html was incorrect.

Comment: by mistake my index.html file moved to some other folder. Thank you, you saved my day

Comment: Yes my index file was missing as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
node --max_old_space_size=8000 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build -e=prod --prod --sourcemap --vendor-chunk=true --build-optimizer
```

For me resizing the max_old_space_size for 8000 worked, the comand is above

Answer (score 1):

try different version of your `@angular/cli`, for ex. on angular 5 this problem was solved with downgrading the angular cli from 1.7.4 to 1.6.8 and all works fine.