# Debugging, Angular 7 production built project by set angular.json sourceMap property

Tags: angular, debugging, build, production

I need to debug/trace front end source codes that written by Angular version 7 and deployed/published on a server, in browser developer tools.

I found some solutions like set some configurations in angular.json but none of them works.

angular.json

```
"sourceMap": true

or 

"sourceMap": {
  "hidden": true,
  "scripts": true,
  "styles": true
}
```

but does not work.

I need something like webpack:// folder in Sources tab on Google Chrom developer tool to put the breakpoints and could to trace the source code (Typescript) but on production mode that already published on a server IIS.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: How is the application built?
use --sourceMap=true when you build your application

Comment: @Nanotron the Angular project version 7 has been integrated with the .Net core2.1 API, using VS 2019, so I publish/deploy project by VS publish feature, and I have already set

Answer (score 0):

@Nanotron , the Angular project version 7 has been integrated with the .Net core2.1 API project, using VS 2019, so I published/deployed the project by VS publish feature, and I have already set build command in package.json something like this,

package.json

```
 "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod --aot --base-href /ProjectName/",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
```

So I think you mean,I have to modify this built command something like this

```
"build":"ng build --prod --aot --base-href /ProjectName/ --source-map=true"
```

instead of modifing, angular.json file attribute "sourceMap":true in

```
"production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            }
```

Good hint!
 I will try it and will share the results!
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

@Nanotron,

it does not work, the build/deploy process going to Halting at 95% emitting index-html-webpack-plugin (Angular ver. 7),

just like something that we tried with angular cli,

[Halting at 95% emitting index-html-webpack-plugin (Angular ver. 7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55405663/halting-at-95-emitting-index-html-webpack-plugin-angular-ver-7)